# Build error in Ubuntu phone app

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiling, ubuntu-sdk

I am trying to build and run a simple ubuntu phone app in the ubuntu sdk. I am running Ubuntu 14.04

The app type is **QML App with simple UI (qmake)**. The framework I chose is **Ubuntu-sdk-15.04.5**.

The kit selected are **UbuntuSDK for amd64** and **UbuntuSDK for armhf**.

After all, this when I try to build it (without adding anymore code), it gives an error

```
No rule to make target, Manifest.json needed by first
```

In the code it is showing,

```
import Ubuntu.Components 1.3
```

QML Module does not contain information about components contained in the plugin, and that `import` line is red marked.

Comment: How did you install the sdk? Did you use the additional ppa?